# N+1 Query Issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I can't understand why bullect gem is complaining about n+1 queries when I actually included it in my query

Issue

N+1 Query detected

```
AddonTypeValue => [:addon_option_values]

Add to your finder: :includes => [:addon_option_values]
```

Query

```
addon_types = AddonType.includes(addon_type_values:
      [addon_option_values: :addon_option_type]).
      where(addon_type_values: {published: true, design_id: self.id}).
      where{addon_type.addon_type_values.visible_for != not_for}
```

My view - jbuilder

```
json.addon_option_values addon_type_value.addon_option_values do |aov|

    json.id aov.id

    json.p_name aov.p_name

    json.position aov.position

end
```

**Request Output Log - N+1 Query method call stack**

/app/views/api/v1/designs/show.json.jbuilder:45:in `block (2 levels) in _app_views_api_v__designs_show_json_jbuilder___3899644929766612648_11335760'

/app/views/api/v1/designs/show.json.jbuilder:39:in `block in _app_views_api_v__designs_show_json_jbuilder___3899644929766612648_11335760'

/app/views/api/v1/designs/show.json.jbuilder:35:in `_app_views_api_v__designs_show_json_jbuilder___3899644929766612648_11335760'

/app/views/api/v1/designs/show.json.jbuilder:45:in `block (2 levels) in _app_views_api_v__designs_show_json_jbuilder___3899644929766612648_11335760'

/app/views/api/v1/designs/show.json.jbuilder:39:in `block in _app_views_api_v__designs_show_json_jbuilder___3899644929766612648_11335760'

/app/views/api/v1/designs/show.json.jbuilder:35:in `_app_views_api_v__designs_show_json_jbuilder___3899644929766612648_11335760'